# Can't generate Flat Modelica Code in Dymola?

Tags: modelica, dymola

I am using a commercial library in Dymola, but I can't generate the Flat Modelica code, or .mof file, is this because of encryption?

Are there some alternatives that allow me to see the Flat code?

[image: Screenshot of error message]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When encrypting a library it is possible for the developer to decide what is accessible to the user (like Modelica code/diagram etc. being visible or not). One of the options is to allow or deny the generation of flat Modelica code using the `showFlat`-flag within the encryption-annotation. Seems the library you are using, has this annotation set to not allow generation of flat code. This will result in what your screenshot shows and also disable the generation of the respective `.mof` files, ignoring the options in the translation settings.

As far as I know, there is no option to generate flat code in this case.

It is possible to set this flag for single models e.g. if there is one model that is especially critical/important or the code shall be hidden for any reason. As far as I know, having a single component disabling the generation of flat code will hide the code of full model. So you could try to find out if this is a global setting or just some components. This is likely only possible by removing components...

Comment: Is it the same Dymola flag for both the flat.mof file and the translated/transformed flat .mof file?

Comment: I think so, yes.